# Missing DLL files in Windows 7 64-bit. What do I need to install?

Tags: windows, dll

So I have been trying to run a few programs that were built using the .NET 3.5 Framework.  Every time I try to open the programs, I get a new missing DLL error.  I don't really want to just download the DLL files from the web.  Instead, I want to know what program/package I need to install to get everything to work on my Windows 7.  There must be some Windows feature I need to enable or some redistributable I need to install directly from Microsoft, right?

Comment: Can you give the name of the dll's it says it is missing, just to check that it really is Microsoft's dlls and not some 3rd party dll the app uses.

Answer (score 3):

Try to re-install the latest [.net Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851)

Comment: The .NET Framework 4 is a separate product from the .NET Framework 3.5. One does not upgrade the other; they can be installed side-by-side on the same computer. .NET 3.5 must be enabled/disabled from Programs and Features in Windows 7.

Comment: I'm currently re-installing .NET Framework 4.  A few missing DLLs so far have been mfc71.dll and msvcp71.dll.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 has the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 built in, it's a component of Windows you can enable or disable. You could try going to:

> Control Panel → Programs and Features → Turn Windows Features on or off

And disabling "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1", clicking OK, then enabling the feature again.

If that doesn't fix it, you can try the system file checker by typing `sfc /scannow` into the Start Menu search bar or the Run dialog box.

Comment: I actually went here yesterday and enabled all the features.  I might try disabling and enabling.  It seems like Windows 7 just doesn't come with all the DLLs for some reason.  sfc /scannow said I was 100% good.

Comment: @eek142 I can assure you that Windows 7 *does* come with all the necessary files to make .NET 3.5 work properly. It sounds like there's something just generally wrong with your Windows installation, you might consider backing up your files and reinstalling Windows from scratch.

Comment: I agree with you.  It seems that I was trying to run a supplementary program without installing the main program itself.  The main program itself apparently carries all the necessary DLL files.  Thanks.